# How can we add fields from a dataframe into a drop down control to plot data in a web page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, drop-down-menu, plotly

I have this code, which works fine to plot a chart in a web page.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

url = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h8/current/default.htm'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[10]

df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1) #drop the first column 0,1,2 etc
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0) #remove the upper level of multi Index
df.rename(columns = {'Account.1':'Account'}, inplace = True) #Rename Columns
df = df.set_index('Account').transpose() #Transpose the data
#df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\out.csv')
    

#Plot
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot
fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index, y='Commercial and industrial loans',
            hover_data=['Commercial and industrial loans'], color='Commercial and industrial loans',
            labels={'Commercial and industrial loans'}, height=400)
plot(fig)
```

[image]

I can easily pick up the column names from the data frame with the code below.

```
#list(df)
labels = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
```

Now, my 'labels' contains this:

```
Columns: [Assets, Bank credit, Securities in bank credit 2, Treasury and agency securities 3, Mortgage-backed securities (MBS) 4, Non-MBS 5, Other securities, Mortgage-backed securities (MBS) 6, Non-MBS 7, Loans and leases in bank credit 8, Commercial and industrial loans, Real estate loans, Residential real estate loans, Revolving home equity loans, Closed-end residential loans 9, Commercial real estate loans, Construction and land development loans 10, Secured by farmland 11, Secured by multifamily properties 12, Secured by nonfarm nonresidential properties 13, Consumer loans, Credit cards and other revolving plans, Other consumer loans, Automobile loans 14, All other consumer loans 15, All other loans and leases, Loans to nondepository financial institutions 16, All loans not elsewhere classified 17, LESS: Allowance for loan and lease losses, Cash assets 18, Total federal funds sold and reverse RPs 19, Loans to commercial banks 20, Other assets including trading assets 21, Total assets, nan, Liabilities, Deposits, Large time deposits, Other deposits, Borrowings, Net due to related foreign offices, Other liabilities including trading liabilities 22, Total liabilities, Residual (Assets LESS Liabilities) 23, nan, Memoranda, Net unrealized gains (losses) on available-for-sale securities 24, U.S. Treasury and agency securities, MBS 25]
```

So, now, I am trying to add a drop down control to the web page and let a user plot data in a chart, dynamically, based on what is selected from the drop down control.  I modified the plotting code a bit, as you can see below, but I don't know how to feed the 'labels' data into the drop down control.

```
#Plot
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot
fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index, y=labels,
            hover_data=labels, color=labels,
            labels={labels}, height=400)
plot(fig)
```

Comment: I think you can read the dash docs. Plotly is often used with dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start would be the [Plotly documentation for Dropdown Menus](https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/). This is by no means a complete answer, but borrowing heavily from [this Plotly Community Forum answer](https://community.plotly.com/t/dropdown-choose-pandas-df-column-and-update-plot-with-corresponding-data/9203), we can drop `NaN` from your columns, and create a buttonlist for your menu.

A few things you might want to add (and things I'll look into when time permits): (1) make the bars different colors, (2) update the y-axis title to match the column name

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

url = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h8/current/default.htm'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[10]

df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1) #drop the first column 0,1,2 etc
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0) #remove the upper level of multi Index
df.rename(columns = {'Account.1':'Account'}, inplace = True) #Rename Columns
df = df.set_index('Account').transpose() #Transpose the data
#df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\out.csv')
    

#Plot
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot


fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index, height=400)
# plot(fig)

buttonlist = []
for label in df.columns.dropna():
    buttonlist.append(
        dict(
            args=['y',[df[str(label)]]],
            label=str(label),
            method='restyle'
        )
    )

fig.update_layout(
    # Add dropdown
    updatemenus=[
        go.layout.Updatemenu(
            buttons=buttonlist,
            direction="down",
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
            showactive=True,
            x=0.1,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.1,
            yanchor="top"
        ),
    ],
    autosize=True,
    yaxis={'title':'Value'},
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!  That looks pretty sweet in the video.  However, I am getting this error message on my side: args=['y',[df[str(label)]]],

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: That's really strange: `str` is a built-in function for typecasting. Have you used `str` as a variable anywhere in your program?

Comment: But technically `str` isn't needed. You can remove `str` wherever you see it since your column names are already strings.

Comment: I took it out and it's working fine!!  It's weird, because I use the str function all the time for all kinds of other things.  Maybe I need to re-start the kernel.  Definitely bizarre.  Anyway, thanks so much!!  This is totally awesome!!